# Setting VSTO Add-In FriendlyName and Description in VSTO Manifest

Tags: vsto

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop an Outlook plugin. What do I need to set in my project so that when Visual Studio builds my VSTO's manifest the manifest has the correct FriendlyName and Description?  How do I change this?

I attempted to change the assembly information but that does not have any effect on the friendly name and description in the manifest that is generated by the build.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019 I was able to do it by editing the csproj file.
I added FriendlyName and OfficeApplicationDescription below AssemblyName.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the manifest file manually. VSTO doesn't provide any specific properties in the UI for that.

[`<friendlyName>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/friendlyname-element-office-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and [`<description>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/description-element-office-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) elements are described in depth in MSDN. You can read more about possible elements in the [Application manifests for Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/application-manifests-for-office-solutions?view=vs-2019) article.

Here is what the articles says:

> You can manually edit application and deployment manifests in Office solutions. Afterwards, you must re-sign the application and deployment manifests by using the Manifest Generation and Editing Tool (mage.exe and mageui.exe). For more information, see [How to: Re-sign application and deployment manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-re-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2019).